# Счётчик строк

Tags: скрипт, python

Пытаюсь собрать простой скрипт, прописывающий номера строк в полученном файле, с выводом в новый файл. Практически готов, но не хватает маленькой функции: на пустых строках счётчик должен сбрасываться:

```
1 Это
2 простой
3 текст
4 .

1 И
2 ещё
3 .
```

Есть следующий код:

> ```
> infile=open('текст.txt', 'r')
> lines=infile.readlines()
> infile.close()
> outtext = ['%d %s' % (i+1, line) for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
> outfile = open("текст2.txt","w")
> outfile.writelines(str("".join(outtext)))
> outfile.close()
> ```

Признателен за любую помощь.

---

**ДОБАВКА**

Спасибо пользователю [[@vinger4](/users/14024/vinger4)](/users/14024/vinger4) за предложенные решения.

```
infile=open("text.txt", 'r')
lines=infile.readlines()
infile.close()
i = 0
outtext = list()
for line in lines:
    if line == "\n":
        i = 0
        outtext.append("\n")
    else:
        outtext.append("%d %s" % (i+1, line))
        i += 1
outfile = open("text2.txt","w")
outfile.writelines(str("".join(outtext)))
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = 0
outtext = list()
for line in lines:
    if not line:
        i = 0
    else:
        outtext.append('%d %s' % (i+1, line))
        i += 1
```

правильно ли я понял логику?

Comment: `infile=open('text.txt', 'r') 
lines=infile.readlines()
infile.close()
i = 0 
outtext = list() 
for line in lines: 
    if not line:
        i = 0 
        outtext.append('')
    else:
        outtext.append('%d %s' % (i+1, line))
        i += 1 
outfile = open("текст2.txt","w") 
outfile.writelines("\n".join(outtext)) 
outfile.close()`

Comment: проверьте корректно ли отрабатывает `if not line`

Comment: К сожалению, это выдаёт такую выписку:

1 ﻿Это
___
2 простой






> 3 текст


> 4 .


> 5 


> 6 И


> 7 ещё


> 8 .

То есть получаем лишние строки и нет сброса счётчика на пустых строках.

Comment: попробуйте заменить `if not line` на `if line == "\n"`, все-таки это не пустые строки, а с символом новой строки (или Вы работаете в виндовсе и у вас также есть перевод каретки? посмотрите чему равен `line` при пустой строке).

Comment: Пустые строки -- дело хитрое. Они могут быть не совсем пустыми. Попробуйте заменить

    if not line:

на 

    if re.match("\s*$", line) :

ну то, что ранее д.б. `import re`, догадаетесь сами

Comment: Ага, вот подправил код, теперь похоже что идеально :)　Принимаю ваш ответ, спасибо!